# excel import with predefined header

Tags: r, excel, import, header

I have the following excel file and want to import that in excel but i need to read the headers in a clean way, to be able to merge the tables.

[image: Excel file]

Comment: how one deal with such headers?

Comment: I would check out tidyxl: https://nacnudus.github.io/tidyxl/. In the documentation there is some information on how to deal with multi-row column headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of merged cells and their values with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/Excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File, ReadOnly = TRUE)
sheet <- xlWbk$sheets(1)
list_Merged_Areas <- list()
counter <- 1

for(i in 1 : 4)
{
  for(j in 1 : 7)
  {
    list_Merged_Areas[[counter]] <-  sheet$cells(i, j)$MergeArea()$Address()
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}

vec_Merged_Areas <- unique(unlist(list_Merged_Areas))  
nb_Merged_Areas <- length(vec_Merged_Areas)
list_Val_Merged_Areas <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_Merged_Areas)
{
  val_Temp <- sheet$Range(vec_Merged_Areas[i])$Value()
  val_Temp <- unlist(val_Temp)
  list_Val_Merged_Areas[[i]] <- val_Temp
}

names(list_Val_Merged_Areas) <- vec_Merged_Areas
list_Val_Merged_Areas

$`$A$1:$G$1`
[1] "Hi"

$`$A$2:$D$2`
[1] "My Name"

$`$E$2:$G$2`
[1] "My Family Name"

$`$A$3`
[1] 1

$`$B$3`
[1] 2

$`$C$3`
[1] 3

$`$D$3`
[1] 4

$`$E$3`
[1] 5

$`$F$3`
[1] 6

$`$G$3`
[1] 7

$`$A$4`
[1] "A"

$`$B$4`
[1] "B"

$`$C$4`
[1] "C"

$`$D$4`
[1] "D"

$`$E$4`
[1] "E"

$`$F$4`
[1] "F"

$`$G$4`
[1] "G"
```